# How to add fixed column plugin in datatable version 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add fixed column plugin to my jquery datatable v 1.9. But I couldn't find the required js file(s) that I need to import. So when I try to call like this:

```
 var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/VMS/Customer/_index",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aLengthMenu": tablelength(),
        "bJqueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
        }
    new FixedColumns(oTable, {
        "iLeftColumns": 2,
        "iLeftWidth": 350
    });
```

In the console it says Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedColumns is not defined. Please someone tell me which files should I download and import and if any other changes are required?

Note: I am not allowed to use any other version of datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's being said, `FixedColumns` is not defined and this is not the right way to do it.

Rather use :

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( oTable, {
    "iLeftColumns": 2,
    "iLeftWidth": 350
});
```

Per the [v1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/) & the [FixedColumns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) doc.

Don't forget to add the [required files](https://datatables.net/download/release) :

```
cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css
cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now its saying this:Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns is not a constructor

Comment: @Exceptionhandler you surely didn't include the `fixedColumns` files then, answer updated.

Comment: After including the files still it is saying Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns is not a constructor

Comment: @Exceptionhandler please make sure you're importing all of the files only once in the page.